# Do creatures with summoning sickness deal damage while blocking?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know creatures with summoning sickness can not attack unless they have haste. My brother is using this to his defense as if you use a 3/3 creature with summoning sickness to block an attack from a 2/2 creature then the 2/2 creature would not die because you are only blocking and not attacking back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the rulebook:

> Unlike other types of permanents, creatures enter the battlefield with “summoning sickness”: a creature can’t 
>   attack, or use an ability that has {tap} in its cost, until it has started your turn on the battlefield under your control. 
>   You can block with a creature or activate its other abilities no matter how long it’s been on the battlefield.

Blocking is not "attacking back". Blocking creatures deal damage normally, whether they have summoning sickness or not. Again, the rulebook:

> After all blockers are chosen, combat damage is assigned. 
>   Each creature—both attackers and blockers—deals damage 
>   equal to its power.
>
> • An attacking creature that isn’t blocked deals damage to the 
>   player or planeswalker it’s attacking.
>
> • An attacking creature that is blocked deals damage to the 
>   blocking creatures. If one of your attacking creatures is 
>   blocked by multiple creatures, you decide how to divide 
>   its combat damage among them. You must assign at least 
>   enough damage to the first blocking creature in line to 
>   destroy it before you can assign damage to the next one in 
>   line, and so on.
>
> • A blocking creature deals damage to the attacker it’s blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All blockers deal damage.

> 510.1d A blocking creature assigns combat damage to the creatures it's blocking.

Summoning sickness only makes it so that you can not tap to activate abilities or attack with a creature the turn it comes into play.

Bonus points: You can tap a creature that comes into play the same turn if you are tapping it as a cost to activate some other ability not belonging to the creature.

Comment: Bonus to the bonus points: the key is whether the ability's cost includes the tap symbol, not whether the ability is on the creature itself. You can tap a creature to activate its own ability if the ability doesn't have the tap symbol in its cost. Example: [Heritage Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152556) can be tapped to activate its own ability the turn it comes into play.